# How this code works?

Tags: android, listview, view, baseadapter

I've written this code from a tutorial.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup,false);

    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgPic);

    SingleRow temp = list.get(i);

    title.setText(temp.title);
    description.setText(temp.description);
    image.setImageResource(temp.image);


    return row;
}
```

In this line of code:

```
TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
```

I think a TextView is copied to a variable of the same kind. and then in this line of code:

```
title.setText(temp.title);
```

we fill that variable with something. then the row variable which is a View and it's not related to 'title' variable is returned.
How it works? I thinks these variables have nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code inflates a new view, settings it's contents. This means that you're creating a new view programatically. It's often used i.e. when populating a list, where you'll have number of rows, each identical in structure, but with different values.

Here is how it works:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // Get the inflater service
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Inflate view with ID = R.layout.single_row into the row variable
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup,false);

    // Get child views of row: title, description and image.
    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgPic);

    // This get's some template view which will provide data: title, description and image
    SingleRow temp = list.get(i);

    // Here you're setting title, description and image by using values from `temp`.
    title.setText(temp.title);
    description.setText(temp.description);
    image.setImageResource(temp.image);

    // Return the view with all values set. This view will be later probably added somewhere as a child (maybe into a list?)
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the method used to return the view for a row in the listview. `row` variable is actually related to `title`, as you can see here.-

```
TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
```

in other words, `title` is a `TextView` inside `row` object, and that code retrieves it to set its text. To sum up, the whole `getView` method is inflating a `single_row View`, and setting properties for all relevant children of `row`.

Answer (score 0):

```
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, viewGroup,false);
```

You are inflating a layout `single_row`

```
TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
```

Initializing textview which is in `singlerow.xml`

```
title.setText(temp.title);
```

Setting title to textview.

You are infalting a layout for each row in listview.

Also it is better to use a viewHolder pattern.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Also you can move the below to the constructor of adapter class and declare `inflater` as a class member

```
 inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

The below link may be of interest to you

[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)